# I'm using a table top row as header. How can I hide it?

Tags: css

In [this](https://praticandoesporte.com.br/melhores-capacetes-para-ciclismo/) WordPress website, I am using a table top row as header (this is the only way of making the background of even and odd rows look good on mobile). Although it looks okay on desktop, it doesn't look good at all on mobile because it repeats the header every line. In fact, I wouldn't like the top row to appear neither on desktop nor mobile.

This table was created using the WP Table Builder.

I know it sounds off-topic and I apologize if it's inappropriate to ask this question here and you're free to delete it if necessary, but regardless the plugin, I just want to know if there is a way to hide that top row (preferably using CSS) while keeping even and odd rows looking good on mobile.

Since there isn't an ID associated with that top row, I can't set `display:none` for `.wptb-row` because it hides the whole table.

I don't think it's necessary because the solution I'm looking for should work with any table, but this is how the code begins:

```
<div class="wptb-table-container wptb-table-403 wptb-table-container-0">
<div class="wptb-table-container-matrix" id="wptb-table-id-403" data-wptb-version="1.3.12" data-wptb-pro-status="false">
<table class="wptb-preview-table wptb-element-main-table_setting-116">
<tbody>
<tr class="wptb-row">
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Comment: I'm so sorry! I think it's clearer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while, plugin developer helped me with this question.

This is how I am hiding first column on mobile now:

```
.wptb-table-container-matrix [data-wptb-breakpoint=mobile] tr td:first-of-type {
  display: none;
}
```